# Accessing Functional Values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to write a function that return four different variables. I wrote a `smfunctionof.m` file with heading

```
function [a,b,c,d]=smfunctionof(x)
```

where x is a size 20 vectorand under the body I have something like

```
a=x.^2;
b=x.^4;
c=x.^10;
d=x.^12;
```

Now, in the code script, I want access those variables. When I type `smfunctionof(x)`, I recieve an answer (that returns, if I remember correctly, `a=x.^2` or something). But when I continue and write a code something like `a;` or even `sqrt(a)`, it does not return it. How can I make a variable from a function usable, or exactly, how do I use variables in function in main script? I have already included those in arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use `smfunctionof` in your code, you call it as `[a,b,c,d] = smfunctionof(x);`. This way, a value will be assigned to variables `a` through `d`. Note that you are not limited to using `a` through `d`, `[u,vv,www,xxxx] = smfunctionof(x);` will work just as well (though `x.^2` is now assigned to a variable named `u`). Actually, using more explicit variable names would be even better for the readability of your code.